# AS3: addChild doesn't appear on stage

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

Im trying to make a menu but my movieclip doesn't appear on stage. I tested it with a trace and it does start running when 'addChild(currentClip) get executed.

It's objected oriented programming, so i added my whole class.
Sorry for the comments, else i get lost :)

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class IntroClip extends MovieClip
    {
        var currentClip:MovieClip;

        public static const MY_FINISHED_INTRO_CLIP_EVENT:String = "my_finished_intro_clip_event";

        // constructor code
        public function IntroClip()
        {
            startButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openMainGame);
            howToButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openHowTo);
            hiscoreButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openHiscore);
        }

        //Open het spel
        public function openMainGame (event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //Bij klikken IntroClip verwijderen en MainGame toevoegen
            dispatchEvent(new Event(MY_FINISHED_INTRO_CLIP_EVENT));
            currentClip = new MainClip();
            trace('addChild')
            addChild(currentClip);
            currentClip.x=160;
            currentClip.y=160;
        }

        //Open de opties
        public function openHowTo (event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //Bij klikken IntroClip verwijderen en Options toevoegen
            dispatchEvent(new Event(MY_FINISHED_INTRO_CLIP_EVENT));
        }   

        //Open de hiscores
        public function openHiscore (event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //Bij klikken IntroClip verwijderen en Hiscores toevoegen
            dispatchEvent(new Event(MY_FINISHED_INTRO_CLIP_EVENT));
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Should work. Are you exporting it from Flash ? Or it's a separate class, like public class MainClip extends MovieClip? Maybe you don't add any graphics to it? If trace works, then it's probably added to stage. You can check it by running this.getChildIndex(currentClip). If it does not throw exception, then it's added.

Comment: It is a separate class, i'll update my code so you can see what i've imported. It is running, only it doesn't show up on stage.

Comment: ok, could you post MainClip() code or it's too large ?

Comment: the MainClip code is empty at the moment.

Comment: So that's why you can't see it -- there's nothing to display. If you create a new MainClip() and do this.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100); this.graphics.endFill() you'll see on the stage.

Comment: There is a MainClip movieclip, with an empty class. That should work, right? If you want to check, these are my projectfiles: http://eleonara.net/images/AS/

Comment: You mean in Flash you give it an instance name? No, if you want to create it via AS3, you need to export it to code. See here http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/as3link/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main class, Kikkers, method startMainGame, you are removing the currentClip and not re-adding it to stage. The problem is that you add the MainClip in the openMainGame method of the IntroClip instead of adding it in the main class, Kikkers. You should modify startMainGame in Kikkers like this:

```
    public function startMainGame( event: Event): void
    {
        trace("Start Main Game");
        currentClip.removeEventListener(IntroClip.MY_FINISHED_INTRO_CLIP_EVENT, startMainGame);
        removeChild(currentClip);

        currentClip = new MainClip();
        currentClip.x = 160;
        currentClip.y = 160;
        addChild(currentClip);
    }
```

In openMainGame method in IntroClip, you should only keep the first line that dispatches the event.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see anything because the MainClip does not have any graphics. Try

```
public function MainClip() 
{
        this.graphics.beginFill(0xF244A7);
        this.graphics.drawCircle(20,20, 100);
        this.graphics.endFill();
}
```

and when you add it to the stage, you should be able to see something :)